# How to enable multi threading mode in SQLite with sequelize

Tags: javascript, multithreading, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm creating a electron application with SQLite database. This application requires multi threading of database. According to SQLite [doc.](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html#:%7E:text=In%20this%20mode%2C%20SQLite%20can,multiple%20threads%20with%20no%20restriction.), by default SQLite uses serialized threading mode. But I need to enable Multi-threading mode. I know that how to set threading mode with SQLite JavaScript API as SQLite [doc](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html#:%7E:text=In%20this%20mode%2C%20SQLite%20can,multiple%20threads%20with%20no%20restriction.). describes. But I'm using **sequelize ORM**, How can I set sqlite threading mode with sequelize?

```js
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');
const path = require('path');
const cls = require('cls-hooked');

const namespace = cls.createNamespace('P&C.Beejak');
Sequelize.useCLS(namespace);

const db = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',    
    storage: path.join(__dirname, './../database.db')
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: You will need to use the `dialectOptions` argument on your options object. In this case, you should use `dialectOptions.mode` and pass the flags to the underlying connection library.

Comment: @SantiagoValdez, Can you demonstrate how to do this, is it like this  `dialectOptions: { mode: 'SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD' }`

Comment: It depends on the library you are using, for example, in node-sqlite3 you have available the flag `OPEN_FULLMUTEX`.